# Excel - Data Validation formula breaks, when using AND

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make the following checks to a cell:

- Check if is a number >= zero
- Check if it is smaller than the number, which is in another cell on the same column, at row 33.

Therefore I created the following data validation formula:

```
AND(
    NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))>=0;
    NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))<=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"")&""&33))
)
```

Although, when I try to import the above function to the data validation's custom formula (DATA->DATA VALIDATION->ALLOW.CUSTOM), it gives an the message:

`The Formula currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?`

Using alone the `NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))>=0;` works.

Using alone the `NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))<=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"")&""&33))`, also works.

I have pinpoint the problem to the function `NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))<=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"")&""&33))`, as even if I try to do the following:

```
AND(
    NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))<=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"")&""&33));
    TRUE()
)
```

It gives the same error message. Does that mean that there is a bug/limitation/feature into using this formula, inside an AND case, or there is something more to this?

Any lights?

Answer (score 0):

I was ultimately to come around the issue, by replacing the concatenation which takes place in `INDIRECT`, with the `CONCAT` function instead of `...&""&33`

```
AND(
    NUMBERVALUE(CELL("contents"))<=NUMBERVALUE(INDIRECT(CONCAT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4);"1";"");33)));
    TRUE()
)
```